# bedr: Binary Availability checking for path all FAIL in R

Tags: r, rstudio

This is my first time using bedr. Upon loading the library all of the binary availbility checks fail.

```
library("bedr", lib.loc="~/R/R-3.4.4/library")
```

> #
>   
>   bedr v1.0.4
>   
>   #
>
> checking binary availability...
>
> - Checking path for bedtools... FAIL
> - Checking path for bedops... FAIL
> - Checking path for tabix... FAIL
>
> tests and examples will be skipped on R CMD check if binaries are missing

I was originally using R-3.5 and I read somewhere that there are some bugs with R-3.5 that will cause this so I reverted to R-3.4.4. This didn’t seem to help. Additionally, I am using a company laptop at a new employer and am waiting on gaining adminstrative access to install/download programs as needed. I understand these issues might further complicate the matter. Does anyone have a way to diagnose the true cause of this failure and/or fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can install packages `bedtools`, `bedops` and `tabix`. 
If you are in Unix environment just use `sudo apt install` to install these packages

After that all the checks should be PASS

Comment: I think this is rstudio issue.  I have bedtools and tabix installed and it still fails.